# How do I install OpenCV 3.0 Beta for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

Looked at some old video tutorials and previous answers, but they didn't make much sense to me since I'm a bit of a beginner/novice and they had more specific aspects of the installation process covered.

Essentially, what process do I go about to install OpenCV for Visual Studio and just get started using OpenCV? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the Ceemple plugin for Visual Studio 2013. You can create OpenCV 3.0 projects with it. And it is easy to install.
You can find it [here](https://www.ceemple.com/ceemple-opencv-visual-studio/)